# Zapier Code Step Model Data into CSV

Tags: csv, zapier

I'm looking for help with some JavaScript to insert inside of a code step in Zapier. I have two inputs that are named/look like the following:

**RIDS:** 991,992,993

**LineIDs:** 1,2,3

Each of these should match in the quantity of items in the list. There can be 1, 2 or 100 of them. The order is significant.

What I'm looking for is a code step to model the data into one CSV matching up the positions of each. So using the above data, my output would look like this:

991,1

992,2

993,3

Does anyone have code or easily know how to achieve this? I am not a JavaScript developer.

Comment: Any code or attempt you have done?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I know how to parse the commas into an object, but not how to combine the two strings into one CSV and transforming the rows into columns

Answer (score 1):

Zapier doesn't allow you to create files in a code step. You can, though, use the code step to generate text which can then be used in another step. I used Python for my example (I'm not as familiar with Javascript but the strategy is the same).

### Create CSV file in Zapier from Raw Data

1. **Code Step** with **LindeIDs** and **RIDs** as inputs

```python
    import csv
    import io
    # Convert inputs into lists
    lids = input_data['LineIDs'].split(',')
    rids = input_data['RIDs'].split(',')

    # Create file-like CSV object
    csvfile = io.StringIO()
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    # Write CSV rows
    filewriter.writerow(['LineID', 'RID'])
    for x in range(len(lids)):
        filewriter.writerow([lids[x], rids[x]])

    # Get CSV object value as text and set to output
    output = {'text': csvfile.getvalue()}
```

2. Use a **Google Drive** step to **Create File from  Text**

   - *File Content* = Text from Step 1
   - *Convert to Document* = no

     - This will create a *.txt document
3. Use a **CloudConvert** step to **Convert File** from *txt* to *csv*.